# Xamarin ios Cloud file copy location issue

Tags: ios, xamarin, icloud, icloud-drive

I had connected iCloud using xamarin forms ios. My file copied to icloud without any error. But it saved in **file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~companyname~MobileDoc/** path.

When i checked inside iCloud my file not showing it. But when i search that file, its location shows as iCloud --> MobileDoc--> File.txt. But when i checked inside the iCloud there are no Folder call MobileDoc.

This is the example i tried [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/introduction-to-icloud)

This is the code i am using to save the document.

```
var uburl = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrlForUbiquityContainer(null);

                 if (uburl == null)
                 {
                     HasiCloud = false;
                 }
                else
                 {
                     HasiCloud = true;
                     iCloudUrl = uburl;

                     var docsFolder = Path.Combine(iCloudUrl.Path, "Documents"); 
             var filePath = Path.Combine(docsFolder, fileName);

         FileService.Save(filePath, attachment.Content);
                     if (option == false)
                         FileService.Instance.Open(filePath);
                }
```

Comment: You mean that save file to icloud success,but can not read file there?

Comment: @Junior Jiang - MSFT  File not Not visible.

Comment: If i find my saved file inside the mac it shows in search window. Location is inside the cloud. but if i checked the iCloud its not visible. I don't know what mistakes i did

Comment: Make sure that icloud have data there.When you save data to icloud , you can use `NSMetadataQuery` to check file.

Comment: icloud have manually uploaded files. not visible only uploaded using xamarin ios

Comment: If your `uburl` is not null, that is right.You can provide more code about saving file to iclould.

Answer (score 0):

**Saving iCloud Documents**

To add a `UIDocument` to iCloud you can call `UIDocument.Save` directly (for new documents only) or move an existing file using `NSFileManager.DefaultManager.SetUbiquitious`. The example code creates a new document directly in the ubiquity container with this code (there are two completion handlers here, one for the Save operation and another for the Open):

```
var docsFolder = Path.Combine (iCloudUrl.Path, "Documents"); // NOTE: Documents folder is user-accessible in Settings
var docPath = Path.Combine (docsFolder, MonkeyDocFilename);
var ubiq = new NSUrl (docPath, false);
var monkeyDoc = new MonkeyDocument (ubiq);
monkeyDoc.Save (monkeyDoc.FileUrl, UIDocumentSaveOperation.ForCreating, saveSuccess => {
Console.WriteLine ("Save completion:" + saveSuccess);
if (saveSuccess) {
    monkeyDoc.Open (openSuccess => {
        Console.WriteLine ("Open completion:" + openSuccess);
        if (openSuccess) {
            Console.WriteLine ("new document for iCloud");
            Console.WriteLine (" == " + monkeyDoc.DocumentString);
            viewController.DisplayDocument (monkeyDoc);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine ("couldn't open");
        }
    });
} else {
    Console.WriteLine ("couldn't save");
}
```

According to document ,when you save file to icloud,you need to use `UIDocument` .This will be Safe and stable.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had added your code and save the document using UIDocument as you said. file is saved inside the  path Library --> Mobile Documents ({file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~company name~MobileA/Documents/SJA%20V001-2.pdf}) . But not visible in iCloud. Please help

Comment: is there anything to do to view iCloud syncrnozation file view in icloud?

Comment: Suggesting that you can try with saving a txt file like demo in document,and check it whether work.

Comment: Yeh i Tried. its also going to this path.

Comment: Ok, also can not be saw in iCloud?Suggest that using `NSMetadataQuery` to get your icloud file list,it will show all file.